# How to display mp4 video in videoview from raw folder

Tags: android, video

I am trying to display a mp4 video from a raw folder. The video is supposed to play in a videoview automatically when the app is open. I want the video to begin as soon as the activity is launched (This is the launcher activity). I also want the video to loop and have no sound. My xml is below.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/launcherVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />
```

This is the code I have.

```
String fileName = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/raw/launchervideo";

VideoView mvideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.launcherVideo);

mvideo.setVideoPath(Launcher);

MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);

mvideo.setMediaController(controller);

mvideo.requestFocus();

mvideo.start();
```

}

This code currently does not do anything but display a blank screen when I run the app and I don't know why. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see you use this variable, and I don't see how you define `Launcher` variable.

```
String fileName = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/raw/launchervideo";
```

to open video file from raw folder you can do this way:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileName);
mvideo.setVideoURI(uri);
mvideo.start()
```

I hope it can help solve your problem

Comment: you should call it after view binding (after this line of code)
`VideoView mvideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.launcherVideo);`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the help guys, I figured it out.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.launcherVideo);
    Uri src = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package/raw/video_name");
    videoView.setVideoURI(src);

    //videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    videoView.start();
```

This worked for me.